# How to make two controllers share one controller action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

In my Rails 4 app I have two controllers with nearly identical actions:

```
class InvoicesController < ApplicationController

  ...

  def load
    @invoice = Invoice.find_by(:download_code => params[:id])
    if @invoice
      respond_to do |format|
      format.pdf { |pdf| render_pdf("attachment") }
    end
  else
    flash[:notice] = "Not found."
    redirect_to signin_path
  end

  ...

end
```

---

```
class RemindersController < ApplicationController

  ...

  def load
    @reminder = Reminder.find_by(:download_code => params[:id])
    if @reminder
      respond_to do |format|
      format.pdf { |pdf| render_pdf("attachment") }
    end
  else
    flash[:notice] = "Not found."
    redirect_to signin_path
  end

  ...

end
```

What is the best-practise-way to combine these two in order to DRY up my code?

Thanks for any idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first have `Reminder` and `Invoice` extend a shared superclass or mix in a module to both of them with their shared functionality. I prefer the latter since I prefer delegations and mixins to inheritance.

Secondly, you should create a module to mix into your controllers with a method like this:

```
def download_helper(your_superclass_instance)
  if @your_superclass_instance
    respond_to do |format|
    format.pdf { |pdf| render_pdf("attachment") }
  end
  #all the rest where you replace @reminder or @invoice with @superclass_instance
end
```

With the module containing `download_helper` mixed into your controllers, you would then simply call it like this:

```
def download
  @invoice = Invoice.find_by(:download_code => params[:id])
  download_helper(@invoice)
end
```

And obviously do the same with `RemindersController`.

I am pretty sure there is some clever metaprogramming you can do to make even that first `find_by` call part of `download_helper` so you can simply pass in the `Invoice` or `Reminder` class itself. But I would have to research how to do that, and I think that's bordering on overengineering by being too clever by half and making things less readable in the process.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks a lot. I just wonder if you'd put the `DownloadHelper` into the `/helpers` folder or the `/lib` folder?

Comment: Let me first say my use of the term "helper" might be misleading since *helpers* have long been a thing in Rails related to reusable code in *views* in particular as described [here](http://mixandgo.com/blog/the-beginner-s-guide-to-rails-helpers). That isn't what we are doing, so the nomenclature could be confusing. But semantics aside, I would put it in `/lib` as you say.

Answer (score 1):

Put the shared code in application_controller.rb OR create a module and include it in your controller classes where needed.

Answer (score 1):

When you are building a method to reuse it's nice to make it polymorphic (usable in different contexts with out being specifically adapted). I like to first add an instance method to ApplicationController that makes it easy to infer the model class from the controller name using rails conventions. #controller_name is a useful rails method that does part of the work here for you.

`def model_class
  controller_name.singularize.constantize
end`

Then your method can  then call `@object = model_class.find_by(:download_code => params[:id])` instead of specifically referencing the class it needs to search. After that, I agree with the above answers that you can then extract the method to either a superclass or shared module.

Which of these you choose can be guided by the current complexity of your app. If this is the only shared method you see yourself needing for now just stick it in the ApplicationController, but if that class is already busy or your trying to extract other shared methods, move the code to a new module and mix it into both controllers.

Answer (score 1):

To extend on @errata answer also place the before_action :download at the top of your application controller.rb